# Recursion: sum digits of a number until there is a single digit left

Tags: java, recursion

How can I sum digits of a number in a recursive manner until there is only a single digit left?

Example: with the input `9234`, the result would be `9` because `9 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 18` and then `1 + 8 = 9`.

This is my code for the moment but I want to sum until there is only a single digit

```
int getsum(int n) {
   return n == 0 ? 0 : n % 10 + getsum(n/10);
}
```

Comment: Change (n==0) to (n less than 10). And return n, not 0

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are several possibilities, here is one of them:

```
public static int getSum(int n) {
     int s = getSumHelper(n); // your original (private) method
     while (s > 9)
         s = getSumHelper(s);
     return s;
}
```

EDIT: Your original code for completeness, because there seems to be confusion.

```
private static int getSumHelper(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n % 10 + getSumHelper(n/10);
}
```

Comment: What is getSumHelper () method

Comment: @user4746449 btw your original code works fine too, you just make a step more, result of last division is 0, it's just an improvement, not a mistake. So you can use it as `getSumHelper()`

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum (int n) {
    return n < 10 ? n : sum(n%10 + sum(n/10));
}
```